# If H is hilbert space and $T\in B(H)$ normal then $(g\circ f)(T)=g(f(T)$

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

How to prove the following claim (theorem):
If $H$ is a Hilbert space and $T\in B(H)$ is normal and if $f\in C(\sigma(T))$ and $g\in f(C(\sigma(T))$ then $(g\circ f) (T)=g(f(T))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(t)=t^n$ and $g(t)=t^m$, then
$$
(g\circ f)(T)=T^{nm}=g(f(T)).
$$
If now $f(t)=\sum_{k=1}^m\alpha_k t^k$, $g(t)=\sum_{j=1}^n\beta_jt^j$, writing $g\circ f(t)=\sum_\ell \gamma_\ell\,t^\ell$,
$$
(g\circ f)(T)=\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^m\alpha_k\big(\sum_{j=1}^n\beta_jt^j\big)^k\bigg)(T)
=\sum_\ell \gamma_\ell T^\ell=f(g(T)). 
$$
Now if $g\in C(\sigma(T))$ and $f$ is a polynomial, there exist polynomials $\{g_k\}$ with $g_k\to g$. Then
$$
(g\circ f)(T)=\lim_n(g_n\circ f)(T)=\lim_n g_n(f(T)=g(f(T)). 
$$
If now $f,g\in C(\sigma(T))$, choose polynomials $f_j$ with $f_j\to f$. Then
$$
(g\circ f)(T)=\lim_j (g\circ f_j)(T)=\lim_j g(f_j(T))=g(f(T)). 
$$

Comment: Hi @Martin Argerami thanks! I think you meant $(f\circ g)(T)$ in the forth row? And in the second row in the end you meant $f(g(t))$, right?

Comment: Yes, I mixed lots of $f$ and $g$. It should be fine now, if I didn't make further mistakes.

Comment: Hi @Martin Argerami in the sedoned row i think that itbis still not fixed..can i ask, what you have done looks fine but how it leads to what is needed ?

Comment: The last line is exactly what you are looking for. If it is fine, what is the problem?